# paste concatenated strings if rownames match

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have two data frames which partially look like this:

d1

```
                SRR1686681 SRR1686679 SRR1686680 SRR1686686 ERR1014349 ERR1014347 
FJ889562.1.1501          0          0          0          0          0          0
JQ236848.1.1432          1          0          1          0          0          0
EU431805.1.1493          0          0          0          0          0          0
EU537467.1.1392          1          0          0          0         10          0
JF500179.1.1495          0          0          0          0          0          0
HM128723.1.1454          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

and d2

```
                taxonomy               X                  X.1               X.2                X.3              X.4                               X.5
FJ889562.1.1501 Bacteria  Proteobacteria  Alphaproteobacteria       Rhizobiales       Rhodobiaceae     Parvibaculum              uncultured bacterium
JQ236848.1.1432 Bacteria  Proteobacteria   Betaproteobacteria   Burkholderiales     Comamonadaceae       Variovorax              uncultured bacterium
EU431805.1.1493 Bacteria  Proteobacteria  Alphaproteobacteria       Rhizobiales       Rhizobiaceae        Rhizobium        Agrobacterium sp. BKBLPu14
EU537467.1.1392 Bacteria  Proteobacteria   Betaproteobacteria     Rhodocyclales     Rhodocyclaceae         Azoarcus                  bacterium SL4.29
JF500179.1.1495 Bacteria  Proteobacteria  Alphaproteobacteria  Sphingomonadales  Sphingomonadaceae  Novosphingobium  uncultured alpha proteobacterium
HM128723.1.1454 Bacteria  Proteobacteria   Betaproteobacteria   Burkholderiales     Comamonadaceae       Variovorax              Variovorax sp. SOD31
```

I want to substitute matching rownames in d1 to the corresponding merged row in 2.

e.g. if FJ889562.1.1501 is found in d2, then it should be replaced by "Bacteria, Proteobacteria, Alphaproteobacteria, Rhizobiales, Rhodobiaceae, Parvibaculum, uncultured bacterium" in d1.

Is this too confusing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would help if you used `dput()` so that we could test out some solutions with your data. To clarify, you want the first _row name_ in d1 to read "Bacteria, Proteobacteria, Alphaproteobacteria, Rhizobiales, Rhodobiaceae, Parvibaculum, uncultured bacterium"?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that? Doing exactly what you want will result in messy data very hard to analyse...

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not answering your litteral question, but telling you what you should do to merge your data and be able to perform interesting analyses on it later. Putting the concatenated taxonomy as row names makes very little sense, typically a XY question!

Stop using row names to store useful information. In a data.frame, the data should be stored in the columns.

So, first, turn your row names into actual columns. Here the row names seem to be unique Ids:

```
d1$uid <- row.names(d1)
d2$uid <- row.names(d2)
```

Now, it seems to me that your end goal is to have all the info in a single data.frame. So what you want to do is join the data.frames. There are lots of way to do this, I personally like the syntax from package `dplyr`. The base R function would be `merge`.

```
library("dplyr")
fused_d <- left_join(d1, d2, by="uid")
```

This will keep all rows in d1, but transfer the info from d2 when there is a matching uid. To keep all rows in d1 or d2, use `full_join` instead.

Side-note: your data does not look properly loaded. 
First, you should avoid loading anything as row names.

Second, the column names of d2 are not right. Why don't you give proper names to all the info constituting the taxonomy? You seem to want to concatenate it, but it is much more useful unconcatenated, for example imagine you want to filter "Alphaproteobacteria", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with merge, see `?merge` for details:

```
> merge(d1, d2, by="row.names")

        Row.names SRR1686681 SRR1686679 SRR1686680 SRR1686686 ERR1014349 ERR1014347
1 EU431805.1.1493          0          0          0          0          0          0
2 EU537467.1.1392          1          0          0          0         10          0
3 FJ889562.1.1501          0          0          0          0          0          0
4 HM128723.1.1454          0          0          0          0          0          0
5 JF500179.1.1495          0          0          0          0          0          0
6 JQ236848.1.1432          1          0          1          0          0          0
  taxonomy              X                 X.1              X.2               X.3
1 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria      Rhizobiales      Rhizobiaceae
2 Bacteria Proteobacteria  Betaproteobacteria    Rhodocyclales    Rhodocyclaceae
3 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria      Rhizobiales      Rhodobiaceae
4 Bacteria Proteobacteria  Betaproteobacteria  Burkholderiales    Comamonadaceae
5 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria Sphingomonadales Sphingomonadaceae
6 Bacteria Proteobacteria  Betaproteobacteria  Burkholderiales    Comamonadaceae
              X.4                              X.5
1       Rhizobium       Agrobacterium_sp._BKBLPu14
2        Azoarcus                 bacterium_SL4.29
3    Parvibaculum             uncultured_bacterium
4      Variovorax             Variovorax_sp._SOD31
5 Novosphingobium uncultured_alpha_proteobacterium
6      Variovorax             uncultured_bacterium
```

From there if you still want to change the row.names to use the taxonomic information you can do so with `paste(..., collapse=", ")` but it's probably not necessary.